# jquery chosen and validation: validation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

There is a state select field and city div.

1) At first state select field is filled and the city div field is empty

2) Once the state is selected, it gets the cities for the selected state using ajax and fills the city div with select box with required attribute.

It worked fine (validation works at this stage). Now I am adding the chosen jquery plugin to city select box in the ajax.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $.post('ajax.php',{stateid:stateid}).done(function(data){
         $('#citybox').html(data).chosen();
    });
});
</script>
```

Chosen works fine, but the validation doesn't work on city select box

Comment: Please post validation code

Comment: jQuery validate ignores the hidden element, check if Chosen plugin adds visibility:hidden attribute to the select

Answer (score 1):

jQuery validate ignores the hidden element, and since the Chosen plugin adds visibility:hidden attribute to the select, try:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(select)" }) //for all select
```

add this line just before validate() function.